# bs4 again from website and save to text file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am learning on how to extract data from websites now and have managed to get alot of information. However for my next website I am failing for some unknown reason as nothing is saved to the text files nor do I get any output in print. Here is my piece of code:

```
import json
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://www.jaffari.org/'
request = urllib.request.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.decode("utf-8"), "html.parser")

table = soup.find('div', attrs={"class":"textwidget"})
name = table.text.encode('utf-8').strip()

with open('/home/pi/test.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(name, outfile)
print (name)
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prayer times are rendered by **java-scripts** therefore you need to use browser tool like `selenium` to load the page and then use beautiful soup to get the data.

You need to download compatible [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) from this link and passed the chrome driver path as i have provided.

Code here to fetch `name` and `prayer times` and saved in a `text` file.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

options = Options()
# Runs Chrome in headless mode.
options.add_argument("--headless")
#path of the chrome driver
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\Software\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver.headless=True
driver.get('https://www.jaffari.org/')
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.sidebar-widget.widget_text>div>table')))
print("Data rendered successfully!!!")
#Get the page source
html=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
#Close the driver
driver.close()

with open('testPrayers.txt', 'w') as outfile:
     for row in soup.select("div.sidebar-widget.widget_text>div>table tr"):
         name=row.select("td")[0].text.strip()
         time=re.findall('(\d{1,2}:?\d{1,2}\W[A|P]M$)',row.select("td")[1].text.strip())
         outfile.write(name + " " + time[0] + "\n")
         print(name + " " + time[0])

outfile.close()
print('Done')
```

---

Updated data with different file name.

---

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

options = Options()
# Runs Chrome in headless mode.
options.add_argument("--headless")
#path of the chrome driver
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\Software\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver.headless=True
driver.get('https://www.jaffari.org/')
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.sidebar-widget.widget_text>div>table')))
print("Data rendered successfully!!!")
#Get the page source
html=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
#Close the driver
driver.close()

for row in soup.select("div.sidebar-widget.widget_text>div>table tr"):
    name=row.select("td")[0].text.strip()
    time=re.findall('(\d{1,2}:?\d{1,2}\W[A|P]M$)',row.select("td")[1].text.strip())

    print(name + " " + time[0])
    with open(name+'.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(time[0])
        outfile.close()


print('Done')
```

Comment: I wanted to run this on my raspberry pi sondo I have to download the chrome driver?

Comment: Yeah on raspberry pi which is linux

Comment: also @KunduK does your code same the prayer times in text files with the text file name as the prayer? like we did before in my previous question?

Comment: No buddy all data in only single file.You haven't mentioned that so i didn't.

Comment: oh sorry could you please do it for different text files like previously? is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205877/discussion-between-ahmed-b-and-kunduk).

Comment: Hi @Kunduk I have left you a message on chat please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `name` variable needs to be a string rather than a bytes object. Try with

```
with open('/home/pi/test.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(name.decode(), outfile)
print (name.decode())
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It does resolve the print issue. However I cannot seem to scrap the table values from the website for some reason.